# Get records from database which is 5 minutes from current time

Tags: mysql

I have a timestamp column in mySQL database and a table called `alerttime` - which has records in the current format `2018-09-06 15:59:00`

I want to run a query that just shows records that are 5 minutes from the current time and date (in advanced). for example if the time right now was 15:55 - it would show the record with the time (2018-09-06 15:59:00)

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

```
SELECT *
  FROM (`todolist`)
  WHERE `type` = '2' AND
        user_id = '1' AND
        DATEADD(minute, -5, GETDATE())
```

I tried the above but i think it's not the right way of doing it, i just found it in a forum somewhere

Comment: what is the type of db?

Comment: sql is the database type

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM (`todolist`) WHERE `type` = '2' AND user_id = '1' AND alerttime >= date_add(now(), interval 5 minute)
```

Comment: I have tried this and i seem to just be getting 0 results and not sure why

Comment: Your type and user_id are INT or VARCHAR?  If they are int, remove the '
You have data in your table in the future for type = 2 and user_id = 1?  Just try :

SELECT * FROM (`todolist`) WHERE alerttime >= date_add(now(), interval 5 minute)

Comment: Already removed user_id and type from the query and it is still returning 0 results. 

The column structure is set to datetime (tried timestamp) same issue. Not sure why this could be happening!

Comment: Because there is no record in the future!  A timestamp is created with current timestamp.  What you may need, is 5 minute after an alert is created?  Not 5 minute before?

Comment: Yeah so basically in the column i have alerttime which is lets say - set 10 minutes from right now.

when there is 10 minutes before the record, a script is then sending an email to the user telling them they have an alert in 10 minutes time.

So basically, i need to display all records that are 10 minutes in the future from now

Comment: If the query return 0 results, it's because you have wrong data in your table.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the comparison, you are adding -5 mins, but after that you are not comparing that value you might need to compare that with something like this.

```
DATEADD(minute, -5, GETDATE()) < GETDATE()
```

you can also check the references for Microsoft:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

I hope this can help, you just need to compare the result of adding -5 mins with something.